# How to use package in Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, menu, package

I have new to Laravel and have installed the Laravel Dynamic Menu package which is installed successfully in the Vendor folder named `rapidwebltd/laravel-dynamic-menu`.

I don't know how can I use this package in my application to create
the dynamic menu.

One more thing I already run the command

```
 php artisan migrate
```

and required tables for this package were created. Can anyone please
guide me to use this package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the documentation of the package it will be avaiable in github or in its official website

Comment: There is no documentation on github.

Comment: Have you any idea to use the packages inside the vendor folder?